# Good way to catch nulls from Entity-Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Right now I'm doing this, but I don't like it very much:

```
decimal maxId = 0d; 
try
{
  maxId = ent.SaveStates.Max(c => c.Id);
}
catch (Exception ex) //no entries in the db
{
  maxId = 1; 
}
```

Is there a better way to handle nulls from the DB with entity-framework?

Comment: Although it's not an answer, I just want to note that it's recommended to avoid catching `Exception`. When you know what the specific exception type is, use the specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's this:

```
maxId = ent.SaveStates.Count() > 0 ? ent.SaveStates.Max(c => c.Id) : null;
```

I don't think that will cause two queries, but I'd profile it to make sure.

Comment: Assuming that we're talking Sql Server here...open Sql Server Management Studio, and select Tools...Sql Server Profiler. Connect to the db like normal, and select the TSQL_SPs template. Once you do that, you'll see a debug view of all activity on the server. Execute the above statement, and see if there are two SELECT statements executed, or just one (like I think it will be). Profiler is invaluable in seeing what your ORM is actually generating under the covers.